# 'MyMusicStore' is a 'property' but used as a type in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm making a project in MVC project and i have added a `Artist` class but it is showing error in `Album` class where I add `Artist` as a return type:

> 'MyMusicStore' is a 'property' but used as a type in mvc

`Artist` Code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MyMusicStore.Models;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Artist
    {
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is `Album` class where the error is arising in the last statement:

```
namespace MyMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause the `Artist` class is in different namespace `MvcMusicStore.Models` and your `Album` class is in `MyMusicStore.Models` and thus it should be imported saying `using MvcMusicStore.Models;` before you can use that `Artist` type in your model

Comment: Good spot - I was staring at that not seeing the difference!

Comment: @rahul Thank you